# Как из клонированного GitHub репозитория пушить в новый, используя AndroidStudio?

Tags: git, android-studio, android, github

**Дано:**

Клонированный собственный проект (репозиторий `А`) с `GitHub`. Из `AS` создан новый репозиторий (`Б`) на `GitHub`.

**Проблема:**

Коммиты в клонированном проекте пушатся в репозиторий `А`, а репозиторий `Б`остаётся пустым.

**Вопрос:**

Как заставить мой клонированный проект пушить в новый репозиторий (`Б`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открыть консоль, перейти в свой проект в котором нужно заменить url, выполнить команду

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

данной командой можно посмотреть применились изменения или нет

```
git remote -v
```

Android Studio подхватит изменения при последующем запуске

Comment: Слава богам, заработало! =) А в GUI это, получается, никак нельзя сделать? Я понимаю, что чрез консоль трушнее...

Comment: Можно) https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux там есть список GUI-клиентов, платформы тоже указаны. Через Android Studio нельзя, в ней только можно создать ветку, переключиться на нее, смотреть diff, мержить, коммитить и пушить, +- пару фич

Comment: Понял, спасибо)